# Tools for finding broken embedded content

Tags: html, web

We have just changed our website over to using ssl everywhere, but this is resulting in some broken embedded content in browsers.

Is there a tool I can use to crawl the whole site looking for this kind of broken content (mostly video) so I can fix/replace? There's enough content that doing this manually would be a slog. I already use linkchecker occasionally to find 404ing links and such, but this doesn't find broken embeds (afaik).

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by broken embedded content in browsers?

Comment: Videos for the most part, that the browser won't load due to being from a non ssl url. Ends up leaving a blank area on the page.

Comment: Di dyou try Xenu's link sleuth? It has ben around for decades and works well fo rme - http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html

Comment: Are you using a CMS to power the website? For example, WordPress, If you are maybe look for a tool written for that CMS to scan the database and change the protocol for you? E.g. [https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try crawling the site with [Screamingfrog](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd check your webserver log files, depending on what format (ie, Apache common log format) you should be able to see status code (look for 404), the ask-for-but-unfound resource, and the referring URL (what page teh link/embed was on)

Answer (score 0):

If all of your content is supposed to be https or ssl then you should be able to crawl the site with [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) and check for links to on site but not the correct type with [Beautiful Soup 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Just use Scrapy to find all of the pages, parse with BS4 and check the embed elements.